# Trouble Deploying Wordpress Using GAE - Locally Runs Properly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I properly set up the Cloud SQL instance and wordpress runs properly locally. 
When I try to run the following commands, where INSTANCE_IP is my IP address to my Cloud SQL instance I get an error in my syntax:

```
{PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN}/mysql --host=INSTANCE_IP --user=root --password
create database wordpress_db;
exit;
```

Edit, Error Message:

```
{PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN}/mysql --host=xxx.19x.2xx.xx --user=root --password       -> create database wordpress_db;                                            ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN}/mysql --host=173.194.243.33 --user=root --password create da' at line 1
```

If anyone could tell me what is wrong with my syntax that would be great, thanks in advance. 
The following is the wp-config.php I believe is relevant:

```
// Required for batcache use
    define('WP_CACHE', true);

    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db');

    /** MySQL database username */
    define('DB_USER', 'root');

    if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
        /** Live environment Cloud SQL login and SITE_URL info */
        define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/your-project-id:wordpress');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    } else {
        /** Local environment MySQL login info */
        define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    }

    // Determine HTTP or HTTPS, then set WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
    {
        $protocol_to_use = 'https://';
    } else {
        $protocol_to_use = 'http://';
    }
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', $protocol_to_use . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    define( 'WP_HOME', $protocol_to_use . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

    /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
    define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: You need to include at least the error message to get a proper answer.

Comment: Do you run the `create database` command and the login at the same time or login first and create once you entered the password?

Comment: I literally go:
{PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN}/mysql --host=xxx.19x.2xx.xx --user=root --password 
<ENTER>
create database wordpress_db;
<ENTER>

Comment: Did you try to use back-ticks for the db name? At least for dashes in the DB name this usually does the trick.

Comment: Did you mean: create database `wordpress_db`; ?

Comment: You should login first, wait for the prompt, then enter the sql command.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're following a guide from the Google cloud project site.

Here's some solutions:

- First, if you have altered the user name or password during mysql install, make sure you update that in the config.php for wordpress.
- Here's the thing - in MySQL, if you are using the Workbench then all you need to run is:

  **create database wordpress_db;**

As the other script was if you're running it from cmd tool I believe.